# Can't find controller with Moveit

Tags: microcontroller, gazebo, moveit, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the titles says, I can load the robot model with gazebo, start the controller, and receive the robot position from Gazebo, I even can plan the movement, but the execution fails with message

```
[ INFO] [1506956704.438899700, 37.700000000]: Returned 0 controllers in list
[ERROR] [1506956704.438925955, 37.700000000]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ Kuka_kr3__base_revolute Kuka_kr3__fifth_rotation Kuka_kr3__first_rotation Kuka_kr3__fourth_rotation Kuka_kr3__second_rotation Kuka_kr3__third_rotation ]
[ERROR] [1506956704.438944708, 37.700000000]: Known controllers and their joints:

[ INFO] [1506956704.468491442, 37.729000000]: ABORTED: Solution found but controller failed during execution
```

I also noticed, that when loading the rviz, there is an error

```
[ERROR] [1506956691.328915099, 24.714000000]: Parameter controller_list should be specified as an array
[ INFO] [1506956691.328985645, 24.714000000]: Returned 0 controllers in list
```

While doing this I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6Mu1P6FlxY) and I setup the gazebo controller, maybe the problem is here, here is the code:

from the  gazebo control package /config
[kuka_control.yaml](https://pastebin.com/gQQrds1H)

from /launch
[kuka_control.launch](https://pastebin.com/8P9Hfytn)

Here are the topics, when I launch the kuka_control.launch

```
/kuka_kr3/joint_states
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/command
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/cancel
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/feedback
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/result
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/status
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/Kuka_kr3__base_revolute/parameter_descriptions
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/Kuka_kr3__base_revolute/parameter_updates
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/Kuka_kr3__fifth_rotation/parameter_descriptions
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/Kuka_kr3__fifth_rotation/parameter_updates
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/Kuka_kr3__first_rotation/parameter_descriptions
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/Kuka_kr3__first_rotation/parameter_updates
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/Kuka_kr3__fourth_rotation/parameter_descriptions
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/Kuka_kr3__fourth_rotation/parameter_updates
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/Kuka_kr3__second_rotation/parameter_descriptions
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/Kuka_kr3__second_rotation/parameter_updates
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/Kuka_kr3__third_rotation/parameter_descriptions
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/Kuka_kr3__third_rotation/parameter_updates
/kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/state
```

then, the files on the Moveit side:

[controllers.yaml](https://pastebin.com/UsnBuDWt)

[demo_planning_execution.launch](https://pastebin.com/Q26h3XBG)

[Kuka_kr3_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml](https://pastebin.com/NtsrQSB6)

I wonder, where the problem might be, since the topics are present, and I think I've targeted them correctly...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272087/can%27t-find-controller-with-moveit/) by [Fiddle](https://answers.ros.org/users/32064/fiddle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2017-10-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-03**:
As this is a setup created by the construct, tagging their accounts here: @R. Tellez, @Ruben Alves.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-03**:
btw: I know you did not set this up yourself, but I would recommend to *never* use any uppercase characters in any resource names with ROS. So no capitals in pkg names, node names, tf frames, urdf joints or links, etc, etc.

Also: `Kuka_kr3__second_rotation` seems like a rather contrived joint name.

**Comment by [Fiddle](https://answers.ros.org/users/32064/fiddle/) on 2017-10-03**:
The problem was rather trivial one, I forgot to insert a space after a hyphen sign before name part in controllers.yaml.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-03**:
If you include the actual changes that you made to files and post that as an answer then you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason that the controller couldn't be detected was in the controllers.yaml file, rather stupid mistake, but nevertheless:

Original code:

```
controller_list:
-name: /kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/
action_ns: "follow_joint_trajectory"
type: FollowJointTrajectory
joints:
  -  Kuka_kr3__base_revolute
  -  Kuka_kr3__first_rotation
  -  Kuka_kr3__second_rotation
  -  Kuka_kr3__third_rotation
  -  Kuka_kr3__fourth_rotation
  -  Kuka_kr3__fifth_rotation
```

Fixed version (name parameter lacked a space)

```
controller_list:
- name: /kuka_kr3/joint_trajectory_controller/
action_ns: "follow_joint_trajectory"
type: FollowJointTrajectory
joints:
  -  Kuka_kr3__base_revolute
  -  Kuka_kr3__first_rotation
  -  Kuka_kr3__second_rotation
  -  Kuka_kr3__third_rotation
  -  Kuka_kr3__fourth_rotation
  -  Kuka_kr3__fifth_rotation
```

---

Originally posted by [Fiddle](https://answers.ros.org/users/32064/fiddle/) with karma: 64 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yug Ajmera](https://answers.ros.org/users/39769/yug-ajmera/) on 2019-02-01**:
I was getting the same bunch of errors. I changed my controller file, but even then I am getting the same error